# How can I insert a value into an html input with php?

Tags: php, html, input, echo

I am trying to fill out html input forms on a website with variables that I have beforehand saved into a file.

My code looks like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ausgabe" placeholder="Januar 2016" value="<?php
              $myfile = fopen("/Template/newfile.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
              echo = fread($myfile,filesize("/Template/newfile.txt"));
              fclose($myfile);
            ?>">
```

Shouldn't this theoretically work?

I am happy for any help.

Comment: if it doesn't, something failed. Here http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript examples found on severial sites regardinf fopen is not working for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309187/javascript-examples-found-on-severial-sites-regardinf-fopen-is-not-working-for-m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more efficient way of doing it would be,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ausgabe" placeholder="Januar 2016" 
  value="<?= file_get_contents("/Template/newfile.txt") ?>">
```

This is the preferred way to read the contents of a file to a string, as per [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice.
I tried this, but if i use it, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: yes, context of newfile is: testtext     that is all.

Comment: What php version?, Have you tried going directly to the url of the file in your browser? If that works try using the absolute url in the call.

Comment: This actually worked! It was my fault for using a relative path and not absolute!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

While running your code you have made an error. If you remove the "=" sign from line 3. Than this code should work fine. After the edit it will look like this:

```
echo fread($myfile,filesize("/Template/newfile.txt"));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider dealing with the PHP logic in a separate file. Then you could include the file on your first page, keeping your code clean:

```
<input type="text" val="<?php echo x ?>">
```

Where "x" is a variable you created in the separate file.