# Import a CSV file to my PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have problem open the file and read the data in the file.
I manage to select a file to read but fopen() don't seam to open the file at all.
Have one button to select/browse for the file (that seams to work) and then the Import-button that supposedly should open the file and import the data into app.

Here is some of the code:

```
<?php
require_once "inc/common.inc.php";
// and some other
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
  <script>
  function doImport() {
    // Some checks that file is selected and fields to import are chosen.
    selFileName = document.getElementById("ImportFile").value;

    if (($handle = fopen(selFileName, "r")) !== FALSE) {
      fgetcsv($handle);   
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
          $col[$c] = $data[$c];
        }
      }
    } else alert( "Error in file opening!" );
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<p>
  <input type="file" name="ImportFile" id="ImportFile" title="Chose a CSV file" />
  <input type="button" value="Import" onclick="doImport()" title="Import data from selected CSV-file." />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I get nothing from fopen() part, not eaven an error message.

Comment: You are mixing PHP with Javascript here. IMO you should study how things works, read some tutorials and give another try.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309237/4178487

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript examples found on severial sites regardinf fopen is not working for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309187/javascript-examples-found-on-severial-sites-regardinf-fopen-is-not-working-for-m)

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to call a PHP function with JavaScript. JavaScript runs on the client side and PHP runs on the server side, the two cannot be mixed without something like [Ajax](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm).

Try researching [Ajax](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm), or [**pass your data through a form**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) via `_POST` or `_GET`.