# Adding a jQuery tab

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-tabs

Well i am new to jQuery and I was going through Bob tabor's video present in http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/free/javascript-and-jquery-training/ describing how to install and utilize jQuery plugins..

In that he teaches about tab and adding a tab through the source code present at jqueryui.com.. But the source code for jquery doesn't work..

JSfiddle added:

http://jsfiddle.net/shettyrahul8june/mf5dm/

these are the two jQuery codes i am stuck up with..
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().tabs("add","1. Title changed.html","Click-a-Rahul");

```
$("<li><a href='10.jQuery events.html'>Click-a-Rahul</a></li>").appendTo( "#tabs ul");
$("#tabs").tabs().tabs("refresh");
```

As you can see i tried with both deprecated method add as well as the newer one refresh.. Both din't work.. A new tab was added and the styling was perfect.. But there was no content inside the new tab though link was provided..

Any help would be appreciated..

Also i found that when i use the add method, it works for the id such as #tabs-3 but it doesnt work for links...

I got this error in javascript error console..

Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. file:///E:/My%20Codes/Web%20Designing%20and%20Developing/Javascript/Javascript%20Fundamentals%20Microsoft/1.%20Title%20changed.html

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/My%20Codes/Web%20Designing%20and%20Developing/Javascript/Javascript%20Fundamentals%20Microsoft/1.%20Title%20changed.html.

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. 11.Installing%20and%20Utilising%20jQuery%20plugins.html:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.17/themes/dot-luv/images/ui-bg_diagonals-thick_15_0b3e6f_40x40.png

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.17/themes/dot-luv/images/ui-bg_dots-small_20_333333_2x2.png

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.17/themes/dot-luv/images/ui-bg_flat_40_292929_40x100.png

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.17/themes/dot-luv/images/ui-bg_dots-small_40_00498f_2x2.png

Problem resolved.. It was due to cross domain request.. Also i was not using a local server to test my page.. I used wamp and it worked.. Working code is present in http://jsfiddle.net/shettyrahul8june/mf5dm/

Comment: Try finding error's in your browser console.

Comment: Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. file:///E:/My%20Codes/Web%20Designing%20and%20Developing/Javascript/Javascript%20Fundamentals%20Microsoft/1.%20Title%20changed.htm

Comment: what is the browser you are using?

Comment: Your URLs are not valid for jQuery UI.  Download it yourself from jQueryui.com then you can use the answer I posted below.  You can also play with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aQLNN/  This fiddle uses your code.

Comment: Getting a new tab is not my actual problem.. i can get a new tab using my codes.. The contents linked to this tab are not displayed.. For example, consider i linked gfrobenius.html to my tab then i cant see the html content in that tab after linking.. I hope now its clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        use the below code and customize as your need , please give localfile url , while working in localhost, live site url not supported , i had mentioned info.php in href ,change it to filename           
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Function</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.17/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css" />
        </head>
            <body>
        <h1 id="title">Installing and Utilising the plugins</h1>
        <div class="demo">
              <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                  <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
                </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                  <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.
                    Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum
                    quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus
                    lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna
                    quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor
                    vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris
                    vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum.
                    Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
                </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                  <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida
                    ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie
                    turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie
                    lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem.
                    Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros
                    vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare
                    consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam
                    erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque
                    pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel
                    felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
                </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">
                  <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti.
                    Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat,
                    eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent
                    taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
                    himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque.
                    Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem
                    enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
                  <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper
                    at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo
                    vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti.
                    Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros,
                    id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero
                    sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat
                    porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu
                    tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit.
                    Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
                </div>
          </div>
            </div>
        <p><a href="http://asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNjQueryUI1817.ashx">Check out the themes
            on this page</a></p>
        </body>
            </html>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            $("<li><a href='info.php'>Click-a-Rahul</a></li>").appendTo( "#tabs ul");
        $("#tabs").tabs().tabs("refresh");
            </script>
```

Comment: i tried it and works for me without any issue . please check it http://jsfiddle.net/mf5dm/1/

Comment: hey your code works.. But its a link.. I tried using a different link.. Didn't work.. Also doesn't work for local file in my PC..

Comment: i think your are giving wrong location in href , so only it not working ,paste the file in same place where your html code is and try to link with file name in href, if this work ,then you are absolutely referring to wrong location

Comment: jsfiddle.net/mf5dm/1 this fiddle is working fine for me in chrome

Comment: Sorry.. I mean i used the link which u provided for the tab in my actual file and then i had executed the html file in chrome.. Tab is empty and the link does not work.. But i do accept that it works in JSfiddle

Comment: means you use info.php in href ?

Comment: No i used http://fiddle.jshell.net/Hba3E/    It didnt work when i used it in my file created using notepad++ and then when i clicked run in chrome, it didnt work..

Comment: How can i add a local file in my machine to act as a href in JSfiddle so that people like you can actually work with the file i want to link  with the tab??

Comment: give me your folder structure i will tell you clearly

Comment: http://s26.postimg.org/dm5cu3md5/folder.png    This is the image of the folder.. 11.Installing are the files.. the href for the 4th tab is  1.Title_changed.html

Comment: i think you are not using any server ,that the issue ,please use xampp or wamp server and put the whole code inside the htdocs for xampp or www for wamp

Comment: else use E:\full path ...\filename.html  in href , and try

Comment: Woah great.. That was superb.. I  had wamp server.. I was not using it for this example.. It worked.. Thanks a lot!! I ll upload the code which worked for me using wamp on JSfiddle

Comment: I din try the full path one.. I'll try that too

Comment: Sure i did that.. But please do specify how i got the answer so that it'll be helpful for others.. Would be a great help.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code at jqueryui.com DOES work.  Here is a fiddle  created using their exact code: **http://jsfiddle.net/svZrC/**

Use this code or else open your console, find the errors, and tell us what the errors are.

This is just the JavaScript from the fiddle, see fiddle for everything else...

```
$(function() {
var tabTitle = $( "#tab_title" ),
    tabContent = $( "#tab_content" ),
    tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
    tabCounter = 2;

var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

// modal dialog init: custom buttons and a "close" callback reseting the form inside
var dialog = $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Add: function() {
            addTab();
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
    }
});

// addTab form: calls addTab function on submit and closes the dialog
var form = dialog.find( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    addTab();
    dialog.dialog( "close" );
    event.preventDefault();
});

// actual addTab function: adds new tab using the input from the form above
function addTab() {
    var label = tabTitle.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter,
        id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
        li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
        tabContentHtml = tabContent.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";

    tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
    tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
    tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
    tabCounter++;
}

// addTab button: just opens the dialog
$( "#add_tab" )
.button()
.click(function() {
    dialog.dialog( "open" );
});

// close icon: removing the tab on click
tabs.delegate( "span.ui-icon-close", "click", function() {
    var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
    $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
    tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
});

tabs.bind( "keyup", function( event ) {
    if ( event.altKey && event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.BACKSPACE ) {
        var panelId = tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-active" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
        $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
        tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
    }
});
```

});

Comment: This is using a button.. Also how would  i add a local file such as a link to another html file using this??

Comment: This one doesn't use a button, it actually uses your code, and it does add the tab: http://jsfiddle.net/aQLNN/  Not sure I understand your question.  Are you just asking how to set content, like links, in the tab area?

Comment: Yes thats what i said.. I can add a tab.. But i cannot fill my contents in that tab.. Only if i use the id from the same html page then the contents are visible.. For example, if i type $( "#tabs" ).tabs().tabs("add","#tabs-3","Click-a-Rahul"); <- the contents are visible..... else if i use $( "#tabs" ).tabs().tabs("add","1. Title changed.html","Click-a-Rahul");<- like this, the contents are not visibe

Comment: Its not visible that way cause your not adding a matching div.  The href in the tab needs to match the id of the div where the content is.  Here: **http://jsfiddle.net/aQLNN/2/**  Hope this helps.

Comment: This technique different.. This will give me a link with he help of "some content" but this will not open the file in the same tab..       //init the tabs
 $("#tabs").tabs();
 
 //create a new tab
 $("<li><a href='#tabs-4'>Click-a-Rahul</a></li>").appendTo( "#tabs ul");
 
 //create its contents
 $("#tabs").append( "<div id='tabs-4'><a href='1.Title_changed.html'>some content</a></div>" );
 
 
 //refresh so the new one appears
 $("#tabs").tabs("refresh");                                          i did this.. Opens the file in new page not the same tab

Comment: But was a great effort and nice technique

Comment: Oooooh, do you want the content of 1.Title_changed.html to appear in the new tab?  If so, try this: **http://jsfiddle.net/aQLNN/3/**

Comment: Sorry i tried.. Din't work.. Do you want me to try it using a wamp server?? coz right now i am not working on a server

Comment: I got my answer pretty easily with the use of just of 3 lines using a wamp server

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont a jsfiddle page i cant tell exactly whats going wrong. But i can give you a code that worked for me.

HTML Part

```
    <ol id="toc">
        <li><a href="#page-1"><span>Customer Details</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#page-2"><span>Script</span></a></li>
    </ol>


    <div class="content" id="page-1" >
        <p>Put page1 contents here.</p>  
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="page-2">
        <p>Put page 2 contents here</p>
    </div>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/activatables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    activatables('page', ['page-1', 'page-2']);
    </script>
```

and include this javascript file in your html page

activatables.js

```
https://www.assembla.com/code/irt/subversion/nodes/js/activatables.js?rev=2
```

[get the activatable.js file from here](https://www.assembla.com/code/irt/subversion/nodes/js/activatables.js?rev=2)

Comment: Added a JSfiddle.. and my problem is i can get a new tab using the jQuery add method but i cannot get the content in that file

Comment: Are you doing an ajax request o another server to get the contents? Because i can see Access-Control-Allow-Origin not present error. You need to look into Cross Domain requests to prevent that error.

Comment: Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows JavaScript on a web page to make XMLHttpRequests to another domain, not the domain the JavaScript originated from. Such "cross-domain" requests would otherwise be forbidden by web browsers, per the same origin security policy. CORS defines a way in which the browser and the server can interact to determine whether or not to allow the cross-origin request.

Comment: Extremely sorry i have no idea about ajax.. Also i am new to jQuery.. I just followed the tutorial lesson 17 http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/free/javascript-and-jquery-training/     and followed as he said.. but it was working for him... Also after searching a bit i read about CORS and refresh being used instead of add in jQuery.. I tried that but din work.. Also i understood nothing about CORS regarding cross domain request

Comment: Cross Domain request happens when you are requesting for a content from you web page from a domain that is other than the domain which serves your page.In your case you are doing an ajax request to another server and browsers does not allow this for security reasons.

Comment: can you specify where am i making this request and how to avoid it and make my code run??

Comment: You can do cross domain request by setting  Access-Control-Allow-origin header at the domain to which you are doing your request. You need to set its value to your domain name or to * if you want to allow every one to access its contents.

Comment: You can go through this page for further understanding of CORS [CORS tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

Comment: Could you tell me how you are getting the contents for the tabs?

Comment: I went through that CORS tutorial.. But i did understand a few things.. But still din get hoe to implement it nor do i understand that how can a file in my pc can be a cross domain.. I didnt even upload it on a server

Comment: I am not getting anything in the tab.. the tab is empty

Comment: Are you dynamically getting the contents in your tab?if then how? Are you using ajax request?

Comment: No i am not dynamically adding it.. And i don'tthinkso i am using a ajax request.. I ve provided a new fiddle..

Comment: Do you know any file uploading site where i can upload my href linked html file so that i can use it JSfiddle??.. coz i don't think-so JSfiddle gives us an option to upload images, videos or files directly

Comment: so you want the file content to appear in the place where you have your link ?

Comment: Yes.. I wanted the content to open in the same tab

Comment: Then you can use what is done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396906/how-do-i-access-and-read-a-local-file-from-htmljavascript-page-running-locally)

Comment: The post explains how to read contents of a local file and display its contents in a html page.