# Use the home directory in HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, home-directory

I am using the script from "Peter Riber" here:
[How do I access and read a local file from html+javascript page running locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396906/how-do-i-access-and-read-a-local-file-from-htmljavascript-page-running-locally) 
to display a local file on a html page.

Basically, it uses an iframe where the source is the path to my local file:

```
<iframe id='iframe' src = '/PATH/TO/HOME/file.txt' onload='readfile()'> </iframe>
```

and it also uses a "readfile" function.

My question is: how to change in the HTML the hard-coded /PATH/TO/HOME/ in the src to the home directory?

In bash you could use ~/ or $HOME. Please let me know if you also have an answer for Windows. Thank you.

Comment: I may be wrong (someone correct me if I am!) But I don't believe you can access local files via the browser via JavaScript for security reasons...though I suppose if it's just in the HTML...hmm...now I have to think about this a bit...

Comment: You can but it is by default disabled on all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get your OS user's home directory path just by using Javascript and HTML. You can instead try to use a relative path to access the local resource. The path would be relative to your server's document root (if you start the path with `/`) or the location of the HTML document (if you start the path with `./`).