# Webpack: Get map with all names of files in a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm currently trying to get a map of all filenames in a folder within a Webpack project. This is what I've tried:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
const interfacesFolder = '../interfaces/';
fs.readdirSync(interfacesFolder).forEach(file => {
    console.log(file)
})
```

But this don't works because it's no a backend script. So because is Webpack, I'm looking for a way to receive all filenames in my interfaces directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have access to your local filesystem in the frontend, you'll need to provide an API endpoint to gather the information you need from the backend.

There are ways to read the contents of files in the local filesystem, (see [How do I access and read a local file from html+javascript page running locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396906/how-do-i-access-and-read-a-local-file-from-htmljavascript-page-running-locally)) but this will not give you access to a directory listing.