# I have files on a usb drive that I want to access via html on an adroid tablet

Tags: android, html

I have an recipe.html app that is on a usb drive. It has two folders that contain recipes and videos.  I plug the usb drive into my Galaxy tablet and the html open fine but it can't find the files residing in the picture and videos folders.  My question is how do I specify the file paths in the html file so they can be accessed. Hope this makes sense.

Code sample:

```
<div class="item1">
    <p class="Names" >Simple Stovetop</p>
    <p class="Names" > Mac and Cheese</p>
    <a href="Simple Stovetop Macaroni and Cheese.html">
        <img src="Pictures/Simple Stovetop Macaroni and Cheese.jpg" style="width:200px">
    </a> 
    <div id="navcontainer" >
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Videos/Simple Stovetop Macaroni and Cheese.mp4" target="_blank">Video</a></li>
            <li><a href="Recipes/Simple Stovetop Macaroni and Cheese Recipe.pdf" target="_blank">Recipe</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This post may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396906/how-do-i-access-and-read-a-local-file-from-htmljavascript-page-running-locally

Comment: Thanks. The code in the samples only access local files not those on a usb drive.  Thanks

Comment: You specify them relative. And you are already doing that. If it works in you pc or on web it should work on Android too

Comment: `have an recipe.html app` ? You have a recipe.html file?